# Как внести изменения в тег XML?

Tags: python, xml

Пытаюсь распарсить xml файл средствами python 2.7.6 для этого изпользую два модуля

> from xml.dom.minidom import *
>
> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Средствами модуля ElementTree хочу изменить текстовое содержание тега

> P 1.1 /P на P 1.2 /P

для этого написал функцию def men_1_2() но при запуске ни чего не происходит ошибок не выдаёт но и текстовое содержание тега 'P' не меняет. В чём причина ?

```
from xml.dom.minidom import *
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = parse('C:\18101.xml')
xml1 = parse('C:\18101.xml')
xml2 = parse('C:\18101.xml')
tree = ET.parse('C:\18101.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
elem = root[0]

xml = xml.getElementsByTagName('DATE1')
xml1 = xml1.getElementsByTagName('DATE2')
xml2 = xml2.getElementsByTagName('P')

DATE1 = xml[0].firstChild.data
DATE2 = xml1[0].firstChild.data
P = xml2[0].firstChild.data

def men_1_2():
  for elem in root.iter('P'):
      elem.text = '1.2'
  print P_CEL

if (DATE1 == DATE2):

  if (P == '1.1'):
      men_1_2()
  else:
      if (P == '1.2'):
         print ('Programm END')

  else: 
      print ('Povtor') 


else:
    print ('no')
```

Comment: как вариант, выполнение не заходит в ветку с функцией men_1_2. Какая строчка в коде должна менять файл?

Comment: @Эникейщик заходит проверял print. Вот эта строчка elem.text = '1.2'

Comment: Эта строчка не меняет файл. Вы файл прочитали, возможно даже изменили содержание считанного xml, но сам по себе файл сохраняться не будет.

Comment: @Эникейщик а что тогда меняет как правильно сделать ?

Comment: Что, где и как именно показало бы, что файл нужно сохранить? Вы изменили значение переменной в памяти, само оно не сохранится в файл, нужно это сделать. Как сделать - посмотреть в описании модуля, которым парсите xml.

Comment: @Эникейщик вы не совсем то говорите xml файл после применения скрипта не меняется ровным счётом ни как. Хотя данные конструкции должны вносить изменения согласно примера вопрос почему у меня это не происходит  ?

Comment: Это вы понимаете не то. Я нигде не говорил, что файл должен меняться, я как раз и говорю, что вы нигде в скрипте не меняете **файл**. Ваши конструкции вносят изменения **не в файл**.

Comment: @Эникейщик конструкции в функции men_1_2() разве не за это отвечают или я не правильно написал под изменением файла имел ввиду изменение текста в теге P ?

Comment: вы нигде не выводите содержимое тэга "Р", чтобы увидеть, меняется оно или нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик добавил в функцию print P_CEL стало выводить 1.1 значит не меняется

Comment: @Эникейщик что значит то что файл нужно сохранить он у меня открыт в блокноте применяю скрипт не отображается что файл изменён, закрываю файл не просит сохранить. Файл не открыт применяю скрипт открываю файл ни чего не изменилось ?

Comment: ``print P_CEL`` вы добавили не в функцию. Кроме того, данный код выдаст на этой строчке ошибку, а когда вы ее исправите, то выдаст другую ошибку. Поэтому непонятно, что у вас там стало выводить. Говорю еще раз: вы **не изменяете ФАЙЛ ни в одной строчке вашего кода**. Поэтому ни блокнот, ни что либо еще не скажет вам, что файл изменен, потому что вы не изменяете **ФАЙЛ**. **ФАЙЛ** вы не изменяете. Он (**файл**) остается неизменным. Функция men_1_2() изменяет **НЕ ФАЙЛ**. Все. Больше я на эту тему комментировать не буду.

Comment: Вызовите `writexml`

Comment: @Эникейщик мой вопрос Как внести изменения в тег XML? вы на него  ответ не дали, а только развели демагогию.

Comment: Вот не надо только этого. Изначально вы спрашивали про файл, писали про файл и бесконечное количество раз говорили про файл в комментариях. Не надо сейчас делать вид, что другие что-то не поняли, если сам с самого начала говорил о другом.

Comment: @Эникейщик во первых что вы мне ты каете во вторых я переформулировал вопрос и вы это поняли что именно я спрашиваю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть в документацию, то можно найти вот такой раздел [19.7.1.4. Modifying an XML File](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) где описывается как именно модифицировать файл (на самом деле сохранить изменённое дерево):

```
tree.write('output.xml')
```